# Limiting behaviour of a system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, recreational-mathematics

A friend of mine offered me the following problem.

Suppose we have a rabbit and a fox in $\Bbb R^2$. The rabbit starts at time $t=0$ at the point $(0,0)$ and runs with constant speed $(1,0)$. The fox starts at the point $(0,h)$ aat time $t=0$ and runs with speed of absolute value $1$ towards the rabbit. We are to find the established distance between the fox and the rabbit (i.e. $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}$).

I am aware that this problem can be solved via a good choice of variables and a careful analysis of the obtained differential equation. In case you're interested, I can post my solution.

I'd like to find a more  *physics-style* solution (something along a finding a conservation law), any hints will be appreciated.

The answer (spoiler):

> the answer is $h/2$.

Comment: Would it amount to minimizing the angular momentum of the fox/rabbit system? A related problem is that if the rabbit runs along a closed simple curve does the fox path converge to a closed simple curve (it converges to a circle if the rabbit runs on a circle)?

Comment: @Paul Frankly, I don't know. I don't quite see why angular momentum should be at its minimum for $t\to\infty$ - perhaps, you could elaborate a bit more on why you make such a hypothesis? And to your related problem, I have no idea=)

Comment: The vector between fox and rabbit will rotate rapidly to begin with but hardly rotate at all for large t. Angular momentum is a bit much - maybe a limiting condition that the angular velocity of the vector between rabbit and fox is 0. So maybe re-write the DE describing the position of the fox in polar coordinates (centred on the rabbit with angle that between fox and rabbit) and limit condition that the derivative of this angle with respect to t is 0?

Comment: @Paul this idea might work. One of ideas of my solution was to describe the limit as the situation when the angle between their speeds is zero (not its derivative, as you propose). I don't which approach gives a simplier solution.